# Interception for handle http error causes problem

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing a project in Angular 10. I have created a Http Interceptor for handle http error. I have used **"map"** and **"of"** operator. But it showing the below error:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent>'.
> 14       .map(resp => {
>
> Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
> 31   Observable.of(err);

Here is my Interceptor code:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpErrorHandlerServiceService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .map(resp => {
        if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
          return resp;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log(err.status);
          console.log(err.statusText);
          
          if (err.status === 401) {
            // redirect the user to login page
            // 401 unauthorised user
          }          
        }
        return Observable.of(err);
      });
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what is the wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read your entire code but judging from you error you can fix it by using `of` operator:

instead of `return Observable.of(err);` do `return of(err);` and add an import `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

***Edit***

as MikeOne commented you need also to use the map operator:

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(
      map(resp => { ... }),
      catchError(err => { ... })
    );
```

`

Comment: Plus, the .map should be .pipe(map...)

Comment: @Rachid O, I tried with import statement. return of(err) instead of Observable.of(err) is working. but map operator still showing error

Answer (score 1):

there's no more `map` or `catch` operators in the `Observable` object

use `pipe` instead :

```js
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

//...
return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(
      map(resp => {
        //....
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        //...
      })
    );
```

Comment: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
    
    21       catchError(err => {

Comment: please see the above error. I am facing in catchError operator

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, you can just return a message like: `catchError(_ => of('Error happened !'))`. Or update your code in the question to see your new implementation